# Explanation of numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, numbers, typeclass

I would like a clear explanation of `Num`, `Real`, `Integral`, `Integer`, `Int`, `Ratio`, `Rational`, `Double`, `Float`.

Comment: You might like the [graph from the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1270011) that details the relationships between the standard classes and types.

Comment: For starters, does this help? https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers

Comment: You should take a look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_basics_II

Comment: Those resources don't cover anything besides converting from/to Integers, Doubles and Ints.

Comment: @catgocat No, Daniel's suggestion covered much more.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This answer mostly assumes you know the difference between types and type classes.  If that difference is hazy to you then [clear up your understanding](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) there before reading on.

**Num**

`Num` is a typeclass that includes all numeric types.

```
:info Num
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
```

**Real**

Also a typeclass covering those types that can be represented as a real value (the `Rational` type).

```
:info Real
class (Num a, Ord a) => Real a where
  toRational :: a -> Rational
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Real Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Real Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Real Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Real Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Real Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
```

**Integral**

A type class for integrals, you know, `...,-2,-1,0,1,...`.  Types such as Integer (aka big int), Int, Int64, etc are instances.

```
:info Integral
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
  quot :: a -> a -> a
  rem :: a -> a -> a
  div :: a -> a -> a
  mod :: a -> a -> a
  quotRem :: a -> a -> (a, a)
  divMod :: a -> a -> (a, a)
  toInteger :: a -> Integer
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
```

**Integer**

A type, not a type class such as what we've talked about till now, that can represent unbounded integers.  So `2^3028` is a legal value.

**Int**

A fixed-width integral.  In the GHC compiler this is 32 or 64 bits depending on your architecture.  The Haskell language only guarantees this will be at least 29 bits.

**Ratio**

This is a type constructor, so you would say something like `Ratio Integer` to get a type for ratio's of two integers (mathematically `a/b`).

**Rational**

Well a rational is literally a ratio of two integers, understand ratio and you're good:

```
:i Rational
type Rational = Ratio Integer
```

**Double**

A type for double precision floating point values.

**Float**

A type for single precision floating point values.

Comment: `Ratio` is the ratio of two values having *any* numeric type. `Rational` is the ratio of two *arbitrary precision* integers.

Answer (score 6):

There is an interesting image in [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types) showing the relations between classes and their type instances, covering most of the ones you mentioned:

[image]

Concerning the [rational numbers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-Real.html), `Ratio` is just a pair of values constructed with `:%`, without any type constraints on the values, even `String`s are allowed, but some useful functions and type classes are only defined for `Ratio` of `Integral`s. And `Rational` is just a `Ratio` of `Integer`s.

```
data Ratio a = !a :% !a
type Rational = Ratio Integer
```

Comment: This image is outdated, thoug sufficient for this discussion. For clarification, the hierarchy for Functors is now `Functor => Applicative => Monad` and `Applicative => Alternative` and `Monad => MonadPlus`, although that's not being discussed here