# why this code is an error? > 1 :: Integral

Tags: haskell

I know this works.

```
Preulde> 1::Int
1
```

But this doesn't work.

```
Preude> 1::Integral
```

I want to know the difference between Int and Integral.

Comment: `Integral` is not a type, it's a type class.

Comment: You may want to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841767/explanation-of-numbers-in-haskell

Comment: Thanks. I read it. Haskell has various types about number. I'm still confused.

Answer (score 6):

`Int` is a type, `Integral` is a type class. Type classes are used as bounds for type variables, they can't be used as types directly. Perhaps you meant to use `1 :: Integer`, which is the other standard type that implements the `Integral` type class.

If you want a polymorphic `Integral`, i.e. one that can be used as either `Int` or `Integer` (or any user-defined type that implements `Integral`), you can do something like `let x = 1 :: Integral a => a`. Note that here `Integral` is only used on the left side of the `=>` to provide a bound for the type variable `a` and `a` is used as the type on the right side. Also note that you can't actually print the value of `x` without giving it a concrete type as you need a concrete type to select which `show` method to call.

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, I didn't tell a type from a type class. I'll use Integral to bind a type variable.
I have not known `let x = 1::Integral a => a`  works.